# Why Python Pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, etl

An organization is evaluating data transformation tools.
Licensed Tools (SSIS, Informatica etc) Vs Python Pandas

I understand the comparison can be Apples Vs Oranges

1. Why and when can an organization choose Pandas for data transformation over licensed ETL tools (Apart from Cost factor)?
2. In RDBMS data is stored in Disk and SQL retrieves the data. In case of Pandas is the data loaded onto RAM or how is it stored?
3. 100 MB CSV file when  loaded into DF occupies memory more than 100 MB. Why?

Comment: Get rid of the first question, it makes everything off topic. Preferably make the rest into one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When organization lean toward Opensource or have programming expertise in python then mostly they prefer pandas over others.
2. Pandas store data in RAM. but with the help of ***chunksize*** or ***Dask*** you can handle data which is larger than memory.
3. Its because when data is loaded from disk it gets its specific Datatype which is depend upon feature whether its a number,float or string. It could automatically detected for you or you can specified data type with *dtype* parameter.

Hope, It will Help!